# sqlite3. how to compare a field using sql3lite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

im new to sqlite3 im trying to create a log in program and using sqlite to make a database to store all the credentials. i have learnt mainly the basics of making a database but i am stuck at trying to check a field. for example looking for username or a password.

```
 submittedusername = input("|Please Enter your username: ")
submittedpassword = input("|Please Enter your Password: ")

selection = sql.execute("SELECT * FROM credentials WHERE username=?", (submittedusername,))
```

this is what i have got so far and i am aware that this is not the way i should do this but i saw this on a forum i looked for help. any ideas on how i would do this would be helpful even a link to a tutorial etc would be much appreciated.

Comment: The code looks OK. What is the problem with it?

Comment: it kept searching for a column not looking for the variable within the table its self. i am new to sqlite so i am probably missing something important or doing it completely wrong